# PHP artisan run seeder from new folder in /database/seeds

Tags: php, laravel, console, laravel-artisan

I have created a new folder in (/database/seeds/) so for now I have a seeder in such directory (/database/seeds/DatabaseTester/Users.php) and I want to run it in my tests. How can I run my seeder using code in my tests?

`php artisan db:seed --class=` is not working for me, maybe I'm doing wrong, I'm confused.

UPD:

[image]

Comment: Corrected poor image url formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is how its gonna work:***

**add** `namespace Seeder\DatabaseTester;` **to your seeder**

**add** `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;` **at the top of your test**

**use to run** `Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'Seeder\DatabaseTester\Users']);`

This one will work for any folder, just don't forget to add `Seeder\` before your path to seeder.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have updated your question. So, with that in mind, I would recommend you to run `composer dump-autoload` and then try it again.

However, I have to ask you. Why are you using seeds on your tests, and not model factories with faker data?

Comment: Sorry, its just fault in question, I've been trying with `db::seed`

Comment: @DmitriyDembitskyi I've updated my answer, please check if now it can be useful to you.

Comment: I'm using seeders to use users many times. I'm creating automation tests with dusk, so that's why.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide the error you are getting it might help, but it looks as though you are using :: instead of a single :

Try

```
php artisan db:seed --class=Users
```

Comment: `Class Users does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Just run this:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=Database\Seeders\ {your folder}\ {your seed}
```